# How to programmatically add bootstrap popover to a html element in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, popover, ng-bootstrap

My app: **Angular5**, **ng-bootstrap** and **bootstrap 4.0**

I am trying to add a popover to html element directly from code and not by adding directive to the element. I tried by adding popover() but function does not exists. What it the right way to do this?

```
eventRender(model: any, $el) {
    $el.popover({
        title: 'Title',
        content: 'content',
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body'
    });
}
```

There is nothing written how to add popover programmatically:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples

I was searching for the anwser for an hour now and I can't find it. What am I missing, this sould be straightforward :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a little different like this.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'; 
import {NgbPopoverConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({   selector: 'ngbd-popover-config',   
templateUrl: './popover-config.html',   
providers: [NgbPopoverConfig] // add NgbPopoverConfig to the component providers }) 

export class NgbdPopoverConfig {   
constructor(config: NgbPopoverConfig) {
    // customize default values of popovers used by this component tree
    config.placement = 'right';
    config.triggers = 'hover';   
} }
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can now add a popover to the element? Like in may example?

Comment: ngOnInit(){
   $('#Your_element').popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      toggle: 'popover',
      title: 'Title Whatever you Need'
      html: true,
      content: this.name
    });
 }
} This will work for sure. declare var $ before the component.

Comment: I tryed this. but It doenn't work. Your code if for global popover config? I have jQuery imported but it says  "$(...).popover is not a function".

Comment: Why do you want to add the popover to the element on the fly. You can add the popover in html and alter its configuration or open or close when needed programatically.

Comment: If I add popover in html with jquery it does not work. I would like to do like at this example: 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo

Comment: Bootstrap popover is supported by angular 5, you need to install bootstrap 4